# Passing a variable in url wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i want passing the ID of my post in url, for exemple:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('siteurl') ;?>
/page_detail/?post_type=<?php echo $id_post; ?>"></a>
```

it appears url :

http://localhost/mysite/page_detail/?post_type=358

but i can't GET the ID (ID=358)

is there a solution

Comment: hmm i guess this seem like .htaccess

Comment: is id=358 post exist?

Comment: what is the response when you try to $_GET['post_type']?